# error while installing rails and sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-3-upgrade, ruby-1.9.3

Following this [tutorial](http://cicolink.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-install-ruby-rails-and.html#!http://cicolink.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-install-ruby-rails-and.html) here, to install ruby on rails on ubuntu 11.10 with sqlite3

when I run the following command

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I get the following error :

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Also, when I try the command,

```
sudo gem install sqlite3
```

I get the same error

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'sqlite3' (>= 0) in any repository

Also,

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

gem -v
1.8.15
```

**UPDATE:**

Trying to install rvm by issuing the following command at the terminal

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

But, It connects and download a package or so,

```
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch master
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0     10      0  0:00:12  0:00:11  0:00:01   101
100   125    0   125    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:26 --:--:--     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

But then gives the following error :

> Could not download
>   'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/master'.   curl returned
>   status '7'.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have not had this issue, but you could try to state the version

```
sudo gem install rails -v 3.1.0


sudo gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.5
```

Comment: nope, gettin the same error again. Have updated my question regarding RVM. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're working on a Linux based system.

If that is the case, please remove any installations you may have made and check out [this tutorial on setting up the entire RoR stack](http://learning-ruby-on-rails.tumblr.com/post/13540669745/setting-up-ruby-on-rails-with-apache-mysql-rvm-ree) I had written.

(The problem you seem to be having is most likely related to either bad installation of openssl / curl or the fact that you're hiding behind a http-proxy)

Comment: In case you're wondering about RVM, don't. It's the best way to go for many a reason :)